# PHP GPS coordinates showing different divisor in Array

Tags: php, gps, exif

I have searched this but didn't come across anything specific.

I was just wondering, i am trying to reverse geocode GPS coordinates taken from an image using the Google Maps API. I can't seem to get my GPS conversion to end up in the right spot ( if any spot at all sometimes )

I have followed various steps on this site, and others on how to transform the values in the array using these initial values. As i understand it this is equal to Degrees, Minutes, Seconds

```
string '153/1' (length=5)

string '23/1' (length=4)

string '45879/1000' (length=10)
```

The bit that i am wondering about is the 1000. Any examples i have seen all seem to be devised by 100. Could this be what's throwing me off ?

i am just using

```
'$imagedata = exif_read_data("img/photos/IMG_20150510_122914.jpg", 0, true);'
```

to grab all the image data.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured this out after some more snooping around. the last number, 45879 is actually Seconds and Milliseconds.

So 45s and 879Ms. So when performing my conversion i dropped the 879Ms and just used 45s in my setup and baam! ended up at the right location!